# Line height and inline-block causing space between border and element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been working with bootstrap for quite sometime now , i just came across a odd behavior when using `inline-block` instead of `float` , before i describe my entire problem , let me say that i don't use inline-block extensively and also the error seems to have something to do with line height.

Ok so **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/zj78wcom/1/)** is the error , as you can see there is a gap between the nav items and the border , which ruins my design ,now that happened because i change on `float:left` to `inline-block` on the following line:

```
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

So why is this gap occurring ? (i know that using float removes the element from the normal flow and using inline block the element will be back into its normal flow of the document.).

Now i found out that this is actually happening because of the line-height.

TWBS , defaults line height is 1.4 something, so now if i the following line to my code my issue is solved:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 0;
 }
```

The above code is added to the `ul` . Now see how i have reduced the line height to `0` , I have an intermediate understanding of `line-height` , all i want to ask is am i using the right solution here ? and WHY exactly is line height 'causing this error  ?

**P.S.** This is "Why" question , not a "How do i solve this" question. please support your answers with evidence, that would be great :)

Comment: It's not `line-height` as such I suspect...it's the white-space. The line-height setting *co-incidentally* corrects it,

Comment: @Paulie_D , i am aware of the white space common error , is there any way to verify that ? , i used the font:0 solution and it did't work . Thanks though .

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `inline-block` puts a block level element on a line, just like a line of text, and it's then subject to vertical alignment along that baseline. When you set the `line-height` to zero, that fact is obscured because there's no distinction between the various points along a line of zero height.

You can add `vertical-align: bottom;` as below to change how your inline-block elements sit in relation to the baseline, and it should do the trick.

```
.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

The effect should be indistinguishable.

Comment: wont vertical-align only work if you set the div to display:table ?

Comment: Vertical-align is meant to apply to "inline-level and table-cell elements". Inline-block takes a block and puts it into an inline flow in its outer context. So it is an "inline-level element" even though it behaves internally as a block-level element.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! That's why I love this site. The vast store of good information and smart people.

Answer (score 0):

You've added the inline-block to the `ul` element instead of `li`

Change to this;

```
.navbar-nav {
        li{
          float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change display to inline instead of inline-block on your navbar-nav element.

```
navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    display: inline !important;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zj78wcom/15/)**